# I have a site that doesn't' have a ribbon, how do I fix this?

Tags: 2007

I am fairly new to sharepoint, so if I don't use the right words please let me know.
I have inherited a sharepoint 2007 farm and one of the sites doesn't have the usual "site actions" and "browse | page" tabs at the top.
I need to add a new user to the page to allow them to view and edit docs (the page appears to be a document library)
So I can see the site in central admin, but I don't have the user permissions and such that I need. I guess my question is how are these pages managed when the tools are hidden?
Sharepoint designer lets me load the page but again, I couldn't find any user permission settings there.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has access to the site collection. If you do not see the site actions, or are missing menu items, chances are that the account you are using does not have the proper permissions.

You can do this through central administration:

- Open Central Admin
- Click Application Management Tab
- Click Site Collection Administrators (SharePoint Site Management
  Section)
- Click Site Collection Drop Down
- Click Change Site Collection
- Click Web Application Drop Down
- Click Change Web Application
- Click Web Application you want to change
- Click OK
- Type user name you want to add as site collection admin
- Add secondary admin if you choose
- Click OK

Then try to go back to that site and see if you have the access needed.

Comment: OK, the user was set to an old employee, so I changed that to the farm administrator service account. However it did take about 15 minutes and a few re-freshes for the page controls to appear but this fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: And you now have access?

Answer (score 0):

do you have full control on the Site collection, try to add yourself as Site collection admin and then check